# Node.js Braintree integration

Tags: node.js, braintree, braintree-javascript

I'm trying to integrate braintree for my Node.js + React project.

The code below is my server side (node.js) code.
The file gateway.js will get configurations from DB, and will create new braintree gateway for other files(functions) to process payment, and refund.

But, I'm curious that it is good approach. In my code, braintree gateway is wrapped by a function (createBraintreeGateway.). What I'm afraid is performance issue. If everytime customer proceed payment, or proceed refund, this function will called, and it will be huge purpormance loss.

If my code is wrong, what is best approach? Thanks in advance.

```
// gateway.js

const braintree = require('braintree')
const logger = require('../../../infrastructure/logger')
const { decryptWithAES } = require('../../some-folder/helper/encrypt/aes')

const createBraintreeGateway = async () => {
    try {
        const configs = await somefunction.findAllConfigs()

        const getConfig = async name => {
            const checker = configs[name]
            if (!checker) { return null }
            const decoded = await decryptWithAES(checker.value)
            return decoded
        } 
    
        const [ liveId, livePublicKey, livePrivateKey, testId, testPublicKey, testPrivateKey ] = await Promise.all([
            getConfig('live_id'),
            getConfig('live_public_key'),
            getConfig('live_private_key'),
            getConfig('test_id'),
            getConfig('test_public_key'),
            getConfig('test_private_key')
        ])

        const environment = configs.mode === 'live' ? braintree.Environment.Production : braintree.Environment.Sandbox

        return new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
            environment,
            merchantId: configs.mode === 'live' ? liveId : testId,
            publicKey: configs.mode === 'live' ? livePublicKey : testPublicKey,
            privateKey: configs.mode === 'live' ? livePrivateKey : testPrivateKey,
        })

    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`[BrainTree] Error while initializing the gateway: ${error}`)
        throw error
    }
}

module.exports = createBraintreeGateway
```

Here is some other function that will call braintree gateway.

```
const createBraintreeGateway = require('./gateway')

const someOtherFunction = async option => {

    const gateway = await createBraintreeGateway()
    gateway.clientToken.generate(customerId).then(response => {
        token = response.clientToken
    })
```